# Better understanding boost's chat client example

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, boost-asio, boost-thread

first of all, [the code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp)

```
//
// chat_client.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2010 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "chat_message.hpp"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

typedef std::deque<chat_message> chat_message_queue;

class chat_client
{
public:
  chat_client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      socket_(io_service)
  {
    tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint,
        boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_connect, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++endpoint_iterator));
  }

  void write(const chat_message& msg)
  {
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_write, this, msg));
  }

  void close()
  {
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_close, this));
  }

private:

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else if (endpoint_iterator != tcp::resolver::iterator())
    {
      socket_.close();
      tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
      socket_.async_connect(endpoint,
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_connect, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++endpoint_iterator));
    }
  }

  void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error && read_msg_.decode_header())
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length()),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_body, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }

  void handle_read_body(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      std::cout.write(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length());
      std::cout << "\n";
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }

  void do_write(chat_message msg)
  {
    bool write_in_progress = !write_msgs_.empty();
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    if (!write_in_progress)
    {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
            write_msgs_.front().length()),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      write_msgs_.pop_front();
      if (!write_msgs_.empty())
      {
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
              write_msgs_.front().length()),
            boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_write, this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }

  void do_close()
  {
    socket_.close();
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
  chat_message read_msg_;
  chat_message_queue write_msgs_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: chat_client <host> <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], argv[2]);
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    chat_client c(io_service, iterator);

    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

    char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];
    while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
    {
      using namespace std; // For strlen and memcpy.
      chat_message msg;
      msg.body_length(strlen(line));
      memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
      msg.encode_header();
      c.write(msg);
    }

    c.close();
    t.join();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

now I don't understand why did they make `write` function to post a call in `io_service`? so it would be thread safe and no1 would use the socket at the same time? does that make sure that no 2X`async_write` would ever happen? and that no `async_write` and `async_read` would ever be used together?
do I have to make sure that `asynch_write` and `async_read` wont happen both in the same time? or is it safe to do them both at the same time?
btw if I want to make the code run faster I understood i can make 2 (or more) threads to do `io_service::run()` so in that case do I have to use mutexes to make sure the things I wrote above wont happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`io_service::post` is used from the `chat_client::write` public method because `async_write` is a [composed operation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html), and applications need to ensure no other operations are performed on the stream until it completes.

> This operation is implemented in terms
>   of zero or more calls to the stream's
>   async_write_some function, and is
>   known as a composed operation. The
>   program must ensure that the stream
>   performs no other write operations
>   (such as async_write, the stream's
>   async_write_some function, or any
>   other composed operations that perform
>   writes) until this operation
>   completes.

the real work is done in `chat_client::do_write` where a queue of outgoing messages is used.

**edit**:

in the chat client example, there's only one thread invoking `io_service::run` so there are no thread safety issues in the handlers. If you have multiple threads invoking `io_service::run`, you should investigate strands rather than mutexes as I described in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078484/using-boost-sockets-do-i-need-only-one-io-service/4079450#4079450).

Comment: tnx a lot for that!! but still didnt receive answer for all of my questions :)

Comment: tnx 1 more thing: is it safe to have both `async_recive` and `async_send` in the `io_service` when 2 or more threads are using `io_service::run`? not 2Xasync_recives (or 2 async_send) just one of each but both on the same time (if u want to get another accepted answer then write it in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098455/is-it-thread-safe-to-call-async-send-and-async-receive-at-the-same-time)