# Is it thread safe to call async_send and async_receive at the same time?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, thread-safety, boost-asio

I understood that calling `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_receive` (or `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_send`) two times may result in a bad behavior..
Is it OK if i call `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_recive` and `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_send` at the same time?

I am going to have 2 or more threads running the `boost::asio::run` so you need to take that into account..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to be OK.  How else would you perform full duplex async communications on a single service?  You need a receive outstanding at all times for incoming data.

The [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) indicate only that each of `async_read` and `async_write` must be called serially.  For example, for `async_read`:

> The program must ensure that the
>   stream performs no other read
>   operations (such as async_read, the
>   stream's async_read_some function, or
>   any other composed operations that
>   perform reads) until this operation
>   completes.

The docs for `socket` are not specific on this point, it's true.

Comment: @Steve Townsend yea I searched the docs for `socket` and it didn't say anything... I guess I should probably `async_read` and `async_write`.. Is there a reason not to? If I know how much bytes I need... Anyways this has nothing to do with `io_service::post` right? I can use that and `io_service::post` at the same time?

Comment: @grich - I would not redesign based on this concern - hard for me to believe socket cannot be used with `async_send` and `async_receive` concurrently, or that `ioservice::post` will interfere.  Try it, put a lot of load on it in test to see if it is solid.

Comment: well too bad there is no definite answer.. tnx a lot anyway, I gave you +1

Comment: @grich `io_service::post` has nothing to do with the `async_read` or `async_write` free functions.

Comment: @Sam Miller Great, Tnx! what about using `async_send` during another thread is running `async_recive`?

Comment: @grich that scenario is perfectly fine

Comment: @Sam Miller So I just got to make sure not to call `async_send` during another `async_send` is in process (and the same goes for `async_recive`) right? thanks a lot for all your help in the past few days, I really appreciate it!